# Python: Checking if a specific website is open in your web browser?

Tags: python

I have an idea for a program that I would like to try to write. Basically, I'm looking to check if I'm accessing a specific website. Then if I'm on that specific website the program immediately terminates that site.

I want to block a few websites from myself for times when I need to focus on school or work. Say I try to check my Facebook, I want it to close itself no matter how many times I try.

Does anyone know a way to check if a specific website is being opened?

Comment: I do not know of a way to do this in Python (it might exist), but you could write a script that **1** reads the DNS addresses for the site you want to block (nslookup) **2** block these addresses using IP Tables.  And write a script to remove the restrictions later.

Comment: If you use Chrome, there's an extension called StayFocusd that will do this for you.